# Can we create perl objects without using constructors

Tags: perl

Can anybody please help me in understanding if we can crate perl object or class instances without using a constructor ? Is it possible to achieve such scenario.

Appreciate your comments!!

Comment: Perl doesn't have any concept of object constructors.

Answer (score 5):

The main question is *why* would you like to do such thing?

It is possible but it doesn't make sense as object stays uninitialized,

```
use CGI;
my $cgi = bless {}, "CGI";

print ref($cgi);
```